# Not able to push docker image to Docker Hub using Jib plugin

Tags: jib

I am trying to build an image using jib plugin with below configuration from my mac m1.
I have Rancher Desktop installed and configured my personal Docker hub registry access token like below.

Note: I can able to push the image using direct auth credentials in my gradle file.

Using Mac M1

~./docker/config.json

```
{
    "auths": {
        {
          "registry.hub.docker.com": {
            "auth": "dckr_pat_<EncryptValue>"
          }
        }
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.4.0'
}

group = 'com.package'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

jib {
    from {
        image = 'openjdk:17-slim'
    }
    container {
        //jvmFlags = ['-Dmy.property=example.value', '-Xms512m', '-Xdebug']
        mainClass = 'com.package.K8sLearningApplication'
        ports = ['8080']
        //labels = [key1:'value1', key2:'value2']
        //format = 'OCI'
    }
    to {
        image = '<dockerhubuserid>/k8s-learning:latest'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Error log

```
com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/<userid>/k8s-learning' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help
```